# "Flattening" std::set<std::string> for storage and comparison?

Tags: c++, string, performance, stl, set

This might be a silly question based on the fact that std::set<> already has perfectly good comparison operators, but I think I might have an optimization for my specific use case and want to make sure I'm not hurting myself somehow.

Essentially, I have a costly operation that takes as input a std::set&. I'm caching the operation's result so I can just return the result if the same inputs have already been passed in. This does require storing copies of the sets (which I'm doing in a

```
std::map<std::set<std::string>, Result*>
```

, and then doing a search every time the operation is called. Since it is very likely that the same operation is going to be called thousands of times in a row, I would say that the cached std::set is found >99% of the time. I recently experimented with what I thought might be a small improvement, based on the fact that certain characters are invalid in the passed-in strings: I flattened the std::set into a single string, the component strings being delimited with a ':' character. My std::map then becomes

```
std::map<std::string, Result*>
```

and every time the operation is called, the set is flattened and the single string searched for in the cache.

I was actually surprised by the performance improvement. My test run used std::sets containing 5 strings, each 30 characters long, and a run of 10,000,000 searches. On my workstation, the times for each run were

```
 std::map<std::set<std::string>, Result*> : 138.8 seconds
 std::map<std::string, Result>            : 89.2  seconds
```

It seems that, even with the overhead of flattening the set every call, the second method is a huge improvement. I guess my question is: why? Am I doing something potentially bad here that the implementors of std::set purposefully avoided (i.e. potentially causing bad heap fragmentation with the bigger string?) Is it simply because the individual strings in the set are in different locations and have to be compared separately? Am I shooting myself in the foot? It just seems like too obvious an improvement in this specific case to give such a performance boost.

Comment: if you call the function 99% of the time with the same parameter, then I would say there is a problem with the caller rather than with the fucntion itself. Anyhow, cant you add some kind of `id` to your sets, so that the method only needs to compare that `id` instead of the whole `set` ? It sounds like the sets your are passing dont change that often.

Comment: I did oversimplify a bit, the input to the function is the std::set and 2 separate messages to be compared. The set describes a transformation to be applied to the messages before the comparison, and it's building this transformation that is the costly part (applying it is trivial.) The set is almost always unchanged, but the messages are almost always different. Ideally I would have the caller somehow obtain a handle to the transformation and then use the handle instead of the set when calling the comparison - unfortunately this needs to be a drop-in replacement for the existing code.

Comment: Just make sure your separator cannot be part of the actual strings, and you should be fine. Also whenever performance don't forget to bencmark with std::unordered_map or std::unordered_set. However strings are not always the best type to store inside them, because you have to read the whole string to generate a hash, while the opreator< can stop earlier.

Comment: Considering it's a lookup, `unordered_map` might be more efficient. Also, when using strings as keys, and not needing alphabetical order, it can be more efficient to compare string length first. I.e. sort "z" before "aa".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why?

Data locality.

[`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) is usually implemented as a Binary Search Tree. It may be that the search operation is faster due to caching on your machine with `std::string`, in comparison with `std::set`.

Comment: Basically a string can stay in CPU cache, thus a search on it can be faster, while a set cannot (it's sparsed in memory). Some more info about "data locality": http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/data-locality.html

Comment: @roalz ho yeah, I get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider writing a small wrapper around set that keeps track of its address and a version number. It would include overloads of the operations (insert, erase, etc.) that modify the set, and when an insert/erase happens, it increments the version number.

Then to determine equality, you look at only two things: the set's address and version number. If modifications are fairly rare and testing for equality is fairly common, the time saved on comparison is likely to be much larger than the time taken to track changes--IOW, you get a big speed win.

If you have to write a *complete* wrapper (one that exposes *all* of `set`'s functionality) this is likely to be a lot of work. In most cases that's unnecessary though; most typical code will require only a few functions to be made visible--often only two or three.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <utility>

template <class T>
class tracked_set {
    std::set<T> data;
    size_t version = 0;
public:
    typedef typename std::set<T>::iterator iterator;

    std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(T &&d) {
        auto ret = data.insert(std::forward<T>(d));
        version += ret.second;
        return ret;
    }

     iterator erase(iterator i) {
         auto ret = data.erase(i);
         if (ret != data.end())
             ++version;
     }

    // At least if memory serves, even non-const iterators on a `set` don't 
    // allow the set to be modified, so these should be safe.
    auto begin() { return data.begin(); }
    auto end() { return data.end(); }
    auto rbegin() { return data.rbegin(); }
    auto rend() { return data.rend(); }

    // The `c*` iterator functions return const_iterator's, so 
    // they're definitely safe.
    auto cbegin() const { return data.cbegin(); }
    auto cend() const { return data.cend(); }
    auto crbegin() const { return data.crbegin(); }
    auto crend() const { return data.crend(); }

    class token {
        std::set<T> const *addr;
        size_t version;
    public:
        friend bool operator==(token const &a, token const &b) {
            return a.addr == b.addr && a.version == b.version;
        }

        token(tracked_set const &ts) { 
            addr = &ts.data;
            version = ts.version;
        }
    };

    operator token() const { return token(*this); }
};

int main() {
    using T = tracked_set<int>;

    T ts;

    ts.insert(1);
    ts.insert(2);

    T::token t(ts);

    if (t == T::token(ts))
        std::cout << "Good\n";

    ts.insert(3);

    if (t == T::token(ts))
        std::cout << "bad\n";
}
```